# Invertible e converges series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

If T is a linear transformation on $R^n$ with $||T - I||<1$, prove that $T$ is invertible and that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(I-T)^k$ converges absolutely to $T^{-1}.$ (Use the geometric series)